# how to build a mongodb pub/sub (messaging) in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, messaging, publish-subscribe

I'm new with mongodb and I've been searching about how to know when a collection changes but I don't understand the steps, because some uses tails others mongodb.messaging. I need to watch an specific collection to know if any change happens, as soon as a document is inserted a I need to get an alert to do something else. The problem i don't understand what to do first, if I need to configure the messaging queue, etc. Any ideas?  Thanks